# Modbus - writing data multiple times hangs program

Tags: c#, modbus

I have written a program to connect PLC S7-200 in c#. I use dll Nmodbus.

**My goal:** Read data online from PLC and write data to PLC. I use a timer to read data online from PLC.

**Problem:** When I write data more than once, my program hangs.

Button1_click: write data

Button5_click: update Show data

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
        SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM10");
        int count = 1;
        void Update()
        {      
            byte slaveId = 1;
            ushort startAddress = 40001;
            ushort numRegisters = 80;

            // read five registers
            IModbusSerialMaster master = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(sp);
            ushort[] registers = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(1, 0, 80);

            for (int i = 0; i < numRegisters; i++)
            {
                string temp = "Register[" + (startAddress + i) + "]=" + registers[i];
                if (i == 36)
                    label10.Text = registers[i].ToString();
                listBox1.Items.Add(temp);
            }
        }
        private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

            button5_Click(source, e);
            label11.Text = sp.IsOpen.ToString();
           // Update();
        }

        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();        
            //if (sp.IsOpen)
            //{
            //    sp.Close();
            //}
            //Update();
            sp.BaudRate = int.Parse(txtbaudrate.Text);
            sp.DataBits = 8;
            sp.Parity = Parity.None;
            sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            sp.Open();
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            aTimer.Interval = 1000;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;  


        }
        ushort i = 1;
        int j = 1;
        bool flag = false;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sp.IsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    flag = true;
                    aTimer.Stop();
                    j++;
                    label11.Text = sp.IsOpen.ToString();
                    sp.Close();
                    sp.Open();
                    sp.BaudRate = int.Parse(txtbaudrate.Text);
                    sp.DataBits = 8;
                    sp.Parity = Parity.None;
                    sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                    ushort startAddress = 40036;
                    ushort numRegisters = 80;
                    byte slaveId = 1;
                    ushort[] registers;
                    if (j % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        registers = new ushort[] { 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50 };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        registers = new ushort[] { 360, 370, 380, 390, 400, 410, 420, 430, 440, 450, 460, 470, 480, 490, 500 };
                    }


                    // read five registers
                    IModbusSerialMaster master = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(sp);
                    //ushort[] registers = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(1, 0, 5);
                    master.WriteMultipleRegisters(1, 36, registers);

                    //for (int i = 0; i < numRegisters; i++)
                    //{
                    //    string temp = "Register[" + (startAddress + i) + "]=" + registers[i];
                    //    listBox1.Items.Add(temp);
                    //}
                    sp.Close();
                    sp.Open();
                    aTimer.Start();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    sp.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            Update();
        }
```

Comment: @People that vote to close this question. The original question might have been written in 'bad' English, but it wasn't that bad that no-one could decipher what OP meant. If you decide to cast a close vote, explain what OP should improve in the comments, instead of relying on the close reason.

Answer (score 2):

You are constantly opening and closing the serial port and creating new Modbus Master objects each time you try to communicate with the remote device. In addition, it is unlikely that you would need/want to change the serial port parameters (baud rate etc) each time you wish to talk to the device.

(Closing and opening the port is likely to cause you to lose data, and while I can't remember the exact details of using the NModBus APIs as I've not used them for several years, a common usage pattern for this type of comms would involve creating a single Master object to communicate through for your entire session rather than creating multiple ones during the session - these multiple instances may be clashing in some way)

So the first thing I think you should do is break the comms into three distinct stages: Startup (create your communications objects (serial port and master) when you create the form), Interact (talk to and from the device as much as is needed on your timer events), and Shutdown (close the master and serial port when you close the form).

Comment: Thanks you so much Jason Willams.